# JAVA: override interface method

Tags: java, methods, interface, overriding

I have interface:

```
interface operations{  
    void sum();  
}
```

and I want to have classes:

```
class matrix implements operations {  
    @override   
    void sum(matrix m) {  
    } 
}

class vector3D implements operations {  
    @override  
    void sum(vecor3D v) {  
    }
}
```

How to do this?
I tried something like this:

```
interface operations < T > {  
    <T> void sum(T t);  
}

class matrix implements operations<matrix>{
    @Override
    void sum(matrix m){};
    }
}

class vector3D implements operations<vector3D>{
    @Override
    void sum(vector3D v){};
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Read up about generic methods and how they interact with generic classes.

Comment: when implementing operations you must specify which is the actual type i.e. operations<matrix>

Comment: `@Override` has an upper-case `O`.  If you use a lower-case `o` it will be useless.  (Or more likely won't compile.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't add a type parameters to the interface **and** the type. Also you should specify the generic parameters of the interface you implement:

```
interface operations<T> {  
    void sum(T t);  
}



class matrix implements operations<matrix> {  
    @Override   
    public void sum(matrix m){  
    } 
}



class vector3D implements operations<vecor3D> {  
    @Override  
    public void sum(vecor3D v){  
    }
}
```

Comment: I also noticed missing 'public' before methods